# why is the value of LD_PRELOAD on the stack

Tags: linux, memory, stack, overflow, ld-preload

I'm studying buffer overflow and solving some wargames.
There was a problem that all of the stack memory above the buffer is set to 0 except return address of main, which will be:

```
buffer
[0000000...][RET][000000...]
```

and I can overwrite that RET.
So I found some hints for solving this problem.
It was to use LD_PRELOAD.
Some people said that LD_PRELOAD's value is in somewhere of stack not only in environment variable area of stack.
So I set LD_PRELOAD and search it and found it using gdb.

```
$ export LD_PRELOAD=/home/coffee/test.so
$ gdb -q abcde
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048476
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/coffee/abcde

Breakpoint 1, 0x8048476 in main ()
(gdb) x/s 0xbffff6df
0xbffff6df:      "@èC\001@/home/coffee/test.so"
(gdb) x/s 0xbffffc59
0xbffffc59:      "LD_PRELOAD=/home/coffee/test.so"
(gdb) q
The program is running.  Exit anyway? (y or n) y
$
```

So there is!
Now I know that LD_PRELOAD's value is on stack below the buffer and now I can exploit!

But I wonder why LD_PRELOAD is loaded on that memory address.
The value is also on environment variable area of the stack!

What is the purpose of this?
Thanks.

Comment: The environment is put on the stack by `execve(2)` syscall, per the ABI specifications

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I mean that LD_PRELOAD is put on two places.

Comment: @lbyeoksan I'm sure Basile Starynkevitch knows what he is talking about.

Comment: I think you'll find that `argv[argc+1] == environ`, so the complete environment is on the stack, and includes `LD_PRELOAD` if it is set.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Hmm. I don't understand. I think argv[argc+1] is kind of 0xbffffc59 in my question. Then what about 0xbffff6df?

Comment: You must have been solving _The lord of the BoF_'s `golem`. I was writing the same question and I've just found your question on _Questions that may already have your answer_. Haha..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864659/why-is-the-string-specified-in-ld-preload-loaded-on-the-memory-of-setuid-execu

Answer (score 1):

Code to explore the stack layout:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// POSIX 2008 declares environ in <unistd.h> (Mac OS X doesn't)
extern char **environ;

static void dump_list(const char *tag, char **list)
{
    char **ptr = list;
    while (*ptr)
    {
        printf("%s[%d] 0x%.16" PRIXPTR ": %s\n",
               tag, (ptr - list), (uintptr_t)*ptr, *ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("%s[%d] 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n",
           tag, (ptr - list), (uintptr_t)*ptr);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    printf("argv         0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)argv);
    printf("argv[argc+1] 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)(argv+argc+1));
    printf("envp         0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)envp);
    printf("environ      0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)environ);

    dump_list("argv", argv);
    dump_list("envp", envp);
    return(0);
}
```

With the program compiled as `x`, I ran it with a sanitized environment:

```
$ env -i HOME=$HOME PATH=$HOME/bin:/bin:/usr/bin LANG=$LANG TERM=$TERM ./x a bb ccc
4
argv         0x00007FFF62074EC0
argv[argc+1] 0x00007FFF62074EE8
envp         0x00007FFF62074EE8
environ      0x00007FFF62074EE8
argv[0] 0x00007FFF62074F38: ./x
argv[1] 0x00007FFF62074F3C: a
argv[2] 0x00007FFF62074F3E: bb
argv[3] 0x00007FFF62074F41: ccc
argv[4] 0x0000000000000000
envp[0] 0x00007FFF62074F45: HOME=/Users/jleffler
envp[1] 0x00007FFF62074F5A: PATH=/Users/jleffler/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
envp[2] 0x00007FFF62074F81: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
envp[3] 0x00007FFF62074F92: TERM=xterm-color
envp[4] 0x0000000000000000
$
```

If you study that carefully, you'll see that the `argv` argument to `main()` is the start of a series of pointers to strings further up the stack; the `envp` (optional third argument to `main()` on POSIX machines) is the same as the global variable `environ` and `argv[argc+1]`, and is also the start of a series of pointers to strings further up the stack; and the strings pointed at by the `argv` and `envp` pointers follow the two arrays.

This is the layout on Mac OS X (10.7.5 if it matters, which it probably doesn't), but I'm tolerably sure you'd find the same layout on other Unix-like systems.

Comment: first thank you for your answer. I already study stack layout of a process in unix-like OS. But I wonder why LD_PRELOAD value is on two places: in environ and in somewhere of the stack. And first one has format of "LD_PRELOAD=xxxxxx" but second one has format of "???xxxxxxx" where ??? is irrecognizable string. I'm not focusing on environ or argv[argc+1]. What do you think about this? Am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Comment: The data for `environ` is in the same area as the stack, so seeing `LD_PRELOAD` in the stack is not surprising.  The stack may also have been used by the `ld.so.1` code, and it may have copied the string value of `$LD_PRELOAD` into a buffer on the stack, and that information may not have been overwritten yet.  In that case, coincidentally, the data from `$LD_PRELOAD` is on 'the stack' twice, once where the environment is stored and once where the dynamic loader copied it.

Comment: OK. Then LD_PRELOAD's value is copied by dynamic loader maybe. Hmm. It still remains curious thing but I can get some hint. I have to read dynamic loader's source code. Thanks. It was very helpful.